# How to fix Error - "access violation in module 'ntdll.dll' "? VBA code crashes

Tags: excel, vba

I need to split Data of incoming payments by clients and by loans for each client, and save these into different excel files across different folders. Let me explain in detail.

Data description: There is an excel file of around 150k rows, with payments on different loans on various clients. 1 client might have several different loans.

1) Create a folder for each client with the Client ID as a name.
2) create a separate excel file for each loan and only include filtered payments on that loan. Save this excel file with the name of the loan ID, under the folder of the client's ID. (and yes some folders will have several excel files).

I am new to coding, so after a lot of google and youtube, I came up with the code below.

1. I have around 12 columns in the DATA sheet. Column B - Loan ID 
   Column C - Client ID
2. I copy those two columns in the Settings sheet and remove duplicates on Loan ID - since I need to create separate excel files for each LOAN ID
3. Afterward, open a new workbook and copy one-by-one the whole data and create a folder with CLIENT ID as a name.

-

```
Sub Split_excel_into_folders()

    Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")

    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet

    'Get unique loan ids
    setting_Sh.Range("A:B").Clear
    data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    data_sh.Range("B:C").Copy setting_Sh.Range("A1")
    setting_Sh.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))
        data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
        Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
        data_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")
        nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 25
        Dim path As String
        Dim Folder As String
        path = setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "\" & setting_Sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        Folder = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
        If Folder = VBA.vbNullString Then
            VBA.MkDir (path)
        End If
        nwb.SaveAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "\" & setting_Sh.Range("B" & i).Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
        nwb.Close False
        data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next i

    setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

The code actually works wonders, but only on small data. It starts creating folders and saves excels as well, but crashes after creating around 283 folders. with the error:

> "Access violation at address 00007FFE7E3EBE6B in module 'ntdll.dll'. write of address 0000000000000024."

I've tested multiple times, sometimes it crashes because of not enough memory. I am guessing I need to optimize it a little bit so it eats up a little fewer resources. Can you help me, please?

P.S

I think it crashes on the line - `Set nwb = workbooks.add`

Comment: I believe mkdir is max 260 characters so this could be why it crashes

Comment: I don't think that might be the issue. If the name in mkdir would exceed 260 characters then yes, but here the problem was that after creating 280 folders is snaps (I personally think it has to do something with memory, since excel is a bit weak)

Comment: i dont think this is the problem, but put the Dim path As String
Dim Folder As String outside the loop.

Comment: You say there is 150k rows in the payment list. Have you checked how many loans there are? You have declared `Dim i As Integer` which goes to max 32768. Change that to `Dim i As Long` in any case.

Comment: @LuisCurado I tried it, no luck. I checked and it crashes here `nwb = workbooks.add` I assume it has problem with opening a lot of workbooks (e.g. book1, book2, book3..... book280, etc.)  I think there is some kind of limit there

Comment: if they stay open theres a limit set by your memory, but u are closing them. i cant see why is crashing in thar line...

Comment: @LuisCurado I think you had a good feeling about where it crashes. Yes I am closing, but somehow when I open a new workbook it overloads system too much. So I found a solution, an easy fix: 
I moved  nw=workbooks.add outside loop and I am creating only one additional workbook and instead of closing, I am clearing it out. 

**SOLUTION** 
I moved this before loop

`Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1) `

and last part of loop, I changed code to this (instead of closing).  

`
nsh.Range("A:AA").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i
`


It works even faster.

Comment: nice. its a good solucion and faster. Excelent!!!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was opening too many new workbooks and closing them. It seemed to overload excel too much. So instead of creating new workbooks in the loop, I created one before it and inside the loop I was clearing it out. The code became so much faster and works great too.

```
Sub Split_excel_into_folders()Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet
Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
''''' Get unique loan ids
setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
data_sh.Range("B:C").Copy setting_Sh.Range("A1")
setting_Sh.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))
data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Valuedata_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")
nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 25
Dim path As String
Dim Folder As String
path = setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "\" & setting_Sh.Range("B" & i).Value
Folder = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
If Folder = VBA.vbNullString Then
VBA.MkDir (path)
End If
nwb.SaveAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "\" & setting_Sh.Range("B" & i).Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
nsh.Range("A:AA").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i
setting_Sh.Range("A:B").Clear
nwb.Close False
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```